# strange method overload resolution with constrained generic arguments: overload with base class arg always called

Tags: c#, generics, overload-resolution

I have some - probably really stupid - question on overload resolution. 
Suppose there is a constrained generic method `Greet` accepting parameter `person` of type `T` which must derive from `Person`. This `Greet` method then calls some non-generic method in another class passing that `person` as parameter. That non-generic method has several overloads - for the base class and for a derived class. Why is the overload for the base class always called?

Example:

```
public static class Test 
{
  public static void Greet() 
  {
    new SomeClass().Greet(new Person()); // Hi, I am a Person
    new SomeClass().Greet(new Manager()); // Hi, I am a Person -- Why?
  }
}
public class SomeClass 
{    
   public void Greet<T>(T person) where T : Person 
   {
     new Greeter().SayHi(person);
   }
}
public class Person { /* some props and methods */ }
public class Manager : Person { /* some props and methods */ }
public class Greeter 
{  
   public SayHi(Person person) { Console.WriteLine("Hi, I am a person"); }
   public SayHi(Manager person) { Console.WriteLine("Hi, I am a manager"); }
}
```

However, only the SayHi accepting a Person is always called. Why?

Comment: outside of using `dynamic`, overload resolution is performed at *compile time*, not *runtime*. It has to pick one method to compile a call to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has to perform overload resolution for the call of

```
 new Greeter().SayHi(person);
```

At that point, the type of `person` is just `T`, and *all* it knows is that `T` is implicitly convertible to `Person`. Therefore, the only applicable method in `Greeter` is `SayHi(Person)`.

It's important to understand that this happens at compile-time, once - it doesn't occur at execution time separately for each type argument that's used for `T`.

Comment: is there a non-ugly pattern of implementing the same intent (without an ugly chain of `if` statements checking the type of the parameter?

Comment: @AunAun: Make `Greet` a virtual method in `Person` instead of in `Greeter`? Or use `dynamic`...